# bash test for number in range (with float numbers)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

the problem is in this line

```
elif [  "$(echo $a '>' $v06 | bc -l)"  -eq 1  &&   "$(echo $a '<' $v08 | bc -l)" -eq 1  ];then
```

How can I test if the number is in range ?
I know that there might be other solution for this but I want to solve in this way with bc...

```
a=0.1
v06=0.6
v08=0.8

if [ "$(echo $a '<' $v06 | bc -l)" -eq 1 ];then
    echo " <0.6"
elif [  "$(echo $a '>' $v06 | bc -l)"  -eq 1  &&   "$(echo $a '<' $v08 | bc -l)" -eq 1  ];then
    echo " <0.6 >0.8"
else
    echo ">1.5"
fi
```

Comment: Are you aware that you won't run into the elif in this situation? 0.1 is less than 0.6 and you're testing if $a is between 0.6 and 0.8. I've tested it with 0.7 and the test in elif actually works then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use bc:

```
test1=$(bc -l <<< "${a} < ${v06}")
test2=$(bc -l <<< "${a} > ${v06}")
test3=$(bc -l <<< "${a} < ${v08}")
if [[ ${test1} -eq 1 ]]; then
   blabla
elif [[ ${test1} -eq 1 && ${test2} -eq 1 ]]; then 
   blabla
fi
```

I recommend to use braces around a variable (so you are sure 06 and 08 won't be append to `$v`), use double brackets in your tests if you are using operators like `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the only thing wrong is you're using `&&` inside `[ ]` which does not work.

Only `[[ ]]` can contain `&&` for multiple test conditions.

You can put the `&&` outside instead, like this

```
elif [ "$(echo $a '>' $v06 | bc -l)" -eq 1 ] && [ "$(echo $a '<' $v08 | bc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then
```

---

or *even better*,

```
elif [ $(echo "($a > $v06) && ($a < $v08)" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
```

since `bc` actually supports the `(num1 > num2) && (num1 < num3)` notation

p/s: You don't need the quotes around the `$( )` since you're only expecting `0` or `1` as return value

p/s2: You can have quotes within `$( )` even if it's enclosed in quotes e.g.

```
"$(echo "1 + 2" | bc -l )"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can strip the "0." and use the -gt and -lt operators:

```
v06="$(echo $v06 | sed 's/0.//')"
v08="$(echo $v08 | sed 's/0.//')"




elif [  $a -gt $v06 -a $a -lt $v08 ];then
```

Comment: line 43: [: .6: integer expression expected