# Bash integer expression expected

Tags: bash, variables, conditional-statements

To satisfy function requirements I have to retrieve a parameter which is a duty cycle (0-100% in 0.01%).

For test, I wrote something simple like :

```
#!/bin/bash
#

if [ "$1" -lt 0 ] || [ "$1" -gt 100 ]
then
    echo "bad param"
else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

I obtain :

```
root@:~# ./test.sh 11
ok
root@:~# ./test.sh 11,01
./test.sh: line 4: [: 11,01: integer expression expected
./test.sh: line 4: [: 11,01: integer expression expected
bad param
```

How to realise this kind of test ?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using the `,` as a decimal point? As your error is telling you, bash only supports integer numbers.

Comment: You will have to use `bc` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952427/bash-test-for-number-in-range-with-float-numbers for instance)

Comment: @SnP: You can use `awk` for this.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` can only operate in integer arithmetics. If you need floats, use an external tool like `bc`:

```
if (( $( bc <<< "($1 < 0) || ($1 > 100) " ) )) ; then
    ...
fi
```

I would rather switch to a more powerful language for the whole script, though (like Perl)/

Comment: Any reason for the `==` within `[[`, rather than using `-eq` or `((`?

Comment: @TomFenech: Thanks, just a remain of the trial and error :)